# Retrieving data from Firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been looking at the APIs from the Firebase website, however, when I print my snapshot, I get **everything** from my database.

I'm trying to only print the value I just set, which is my variable: `test_person_1`.

```
 import UIKit
 import Firebase

 class Test: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()



    ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in



        var test_person_1 = ["full_name": "Test 1", "date_of_birth": "June 1, 2000"]
        var Test_person_2 = ["full_name": "Grace Hopper", "date_of_birth": "July 1, 2000"]
                    let usersRef = ref.child("New child")


        usersRef.setValue([test_person_1])


        print(snapshot) //


    })
```

Json tree: [image]

Comment: Give your JSON tree. as text not snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time you print the snapshot, the value hasn't been set on the server yet.

If you want to print when the data been sent to the server, add a so-called completion listener to your `setValue()` call:

```
usersRef.setValue([test_person_1]) { (error, ref) in
    print(error, ref)
}
```

If there is no error, you know that the value on the server is what you just wrote. But if you want to read back the value from the server, you'll need to attach a listener for it:

```
usersRef.setValue([test_person_1]) { (error, ref) in
    ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (snapshot) in
        print ("new value \(snapshot.value)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

What if I wanted to retrieve the data later, and not exactly when the data is being sent?
I'm trying to work towards that after an user has written some input in some textfields, on another viewcontroller later I will retrieve and print those inputs.

Comment: You'd attach a listener with `ref.observeEventOfType()` outside of the callback. Did you read the [Firebase documentation on retrieving data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data) or take the [iOS codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/#0)? Both cover such concepts quite well.

Comment: I did spent all day on the "retrieving data" page, however I must admit I might be over my head. Fairly new to programming.. so I just could make sense of it and in the end ended up here. I appreciate for your help, I will take a look at it all. Thank you